# How to render multiple objects based on a changing number

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've done this in Vue before with v-for. But in React I want to add a TextField based on a number in my state. I have a state:

```
constructor(...props){
    super(...props)
    this.state = {
        questions: 1
    }
}
```

My component will have a button which will add 1 to questions if pressed. And I want to render TextFields based on the number in the state (questions). By that same logic I also plan on doing a remove button which will remove one from the total, and will also remove one of the TextFields. I tried this:

```
render(){
    let category_rows = []
    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.questions; i++){
        category_rows.push(<TextField variant='outlined' />)
    }
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography>
                    Add Question Categories
                </Typography>
                {category_rows}
            </CardContent>
            <Button onClick={() => {
                this.state.questions += 1
                console.log(this.state)
            }}>Add</Button>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

}

And it renders the first time but when pressing my button and adding to the state, it doesn't add a new field like I want.

While I'm at it, if someone could tell me if it's possible to take the code on the Button's `onClick` and put it in a function, then call the function on the `onClick`. I tried it but when I log `this` it says it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are changing the state variable wrong

inside your Button instead of doing this

```
<Button onClick={() => {
                this.state.questions += 1
                console.log(this.state)
            }}>Add</Button>
```

do this

```
<Button onClick={() => this.setState({questions : this.state.questions +1 })}>Add</Button>
```

Because in react we shouldn't update the state variable directly. otherwise it will not trigger re render and wont update.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you this worked perfectly. I'm new to React so I miss simple things like this. Is there any way I can put the code inside `onClick` on a function? Like I mentioned, I tried doing a function but `this` came empty.

Comment: No problem . Glad i could help. can you please mark the answer as accepted ?

Comment: Will do in 7 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state wrong way. State should always be immutable and should only be updated by using setState function

```
<Button onClick={() => {
            this.setState({questions: this.state.questions += 1})
            console.log(this.state)
        }}>Add</Button>
```

Comment: Refer to official docs for how state works - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html